# Is anticanonical divisor on complete toric variety big?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

It seems to me that for any complete toric variety $P_\Sigma$, the anticanonical divisor is big. Moreover, the argument also shows that $P_\Sigma$ is projective. This sounds a bit strange for me, did I make any mistake in the argument below?

We can always shrink the coefficient of the anticanonical divisor $$-K_{P_\Sigma} = \sum_{\rho} D_\rho$$ from $1$ to a smaller positive number $a_\rho$ such that $$\sum_{\rho} a_\rho D_\rho$$ is an ample divisor (think about a small ball around the origin, and shrink each ray $\rho$ so that it lands on the boundary of this ball).

Then because $$-K_{P_\Sigma} = \sum_{\rho} a_\rho D_\rho + D$$ where $D$ is a effective divisor, we know $-K_{P_\Sigma}$ is a big divisor.

This argument also shows that complete toric variety is projective (because it always has an ample divisor).

Comment: I  don't understand your argument (or assertion) that shrinking coefficients leads to an ample divisor. Why should that divisor be ample?

Comment: @Relapsarian If the rays land on a ball, the polytope connect them will be convex, hence the supporting function should be strictly convex (just think about the 2 dim case with 3 rays)

Comment: I am not sure that your polytope lives in the right space. But regardless, I suggest you work through one of the standard examples of a nonprojective complete toric variety --- eg. Example 6.1.17 in Cox--Little--Schenck.